# How to make weight painting faster

Tags: animation, armature, weight-painting

I've set up my bones, but my weight panting is slow. Every stroke takes almost forever to show up. I don't know if it's my computer itself or something else. What could be going on?

Comment: is your mesh very high-poly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable all modifiers of the mesh except the one, which binds the mesh to the armature. Additionally set the shader mode to "flat".

Comment: That really worked out well. Thanks for the tip.